# Compiling C file from vim in a "path agnostic" way

Tags: c, vim, ctags, zephyr-rtos

Suppose I launch vim from a large project root folder and want to compile a specific example (I ll use [zephyr RTOS](https://www.zephyrproject.org/) for example). This root folder is located under `/home/<user>/zephyr/`

Let's say I run `vim samples/basic/blinky/src/main.c`.
Now if I want to compile it, I would go, from another terminal to `samples/basic/blinky/build/` and run `make`

If I want to build it without leaving vim, I could run `:make -C samples/basic/blinky/build/`

I would like to automate this process, pressing any key, let's say f5.

So if I have, for example, two vertical splits, v1 and v2.

In v1 I have `samples/basic/blinky/src/main.c` and in v2 I have `samples/drivers/rtc/src/main.c`.

Pressing f5 from v1 would lead to run the equivalent of `:make -C samples/basic/blinky/build/`, and from v2 would lead to run the equivalent of `:make -C samples/drivers/rtc/build/`

The common pattern is that the build folder is located in `../build/` from the current c file directory.

I don't want to "permanently" use `:cd` or `:lcd` to change working directory, even for the current split/window because:

- My ctags tags file is located in the root folder, so I want to be able to jump to any function that `samples/basic/blinky/src/main.c` uses but are not necessarily defined in the same file.

  - If I want to open a new file, I want to access it using its path from the root folder and not the current file path

My current solution is to have a function in my `~/.vimrc` which temporally  changes the working directory to the current file equivalent build folder, so that I can run `:make` and then changes back the working directory to the root folder.

It looks like this:

`nnoremap <F5> :call MakeTst()<CR>
function! MakeTst(...)
    :cd %:p:h
    :cd ../build/
    :make
    :cd /home/<user>/zephyr/
endfunction`

While this works, the downside is that the root folder is hardcoded inside the `~/.vimrc`.

How can I achieve the same result without hardcoding the root folder path?

Comment: How is `cmake` tag related with the problem? (`make` and `cmake` are **different** things).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your constructive comment! You are absolutely right (as you pointed out in a bold point).  I added it as a "lack of thinking" as it is used by the example project to generate the Makefile. Since it is not relevant to the question, I ll remove it.
Cheers

Comment: Would `:make -C %:p:h/../build` work?

Comment: @user58697 Well, I m really stupid for not putting the pieces together myself ... That works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave  the answer yourself:  in your function.  As long as  your file
structure keeps that pattern, you can  use filename modifiers to make it
generic:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :make -C %:p:h/../build
```

This will always build in the directory `build` at the same level of the
directory where the current file sits. Just like your example:

```
a/b/c/src/file.c
a/b/c/build
```

It breaks in a case like this:

```
a/b/c/src/include/features.h
```

As it would try to build in:

```
a/b/c/src/build
```

There is  a workaround  though. If  your `build` is  always at  the same
level of `src`,  then you can perform a text  substitution with the `:s`
modifier:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :make -C %:p:s!.*\zssrc.*!build!
```

This simple  pattern `.*\zssrc.*`  searches for the  last `src`  in your
path  and replaces  it (and  anything after  it) with  `build`. It  does
nothing if there is no `src` in the path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the tip!